# Jersey errors after deploying to tomcat, works fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I've lost hours trying to pinpoint this annoying issue. I've created a simple Java app that exposes a few REST services using Jersey.

When debugging the application in Eclipse, using a Tomcat 8 server, everything works fine. I then export the project to a WAR file, deploy it to a real Tomcat 8 server, and when I try to call the REST services, I get the below error. I've checked the obvious things: making sure I'm using the correct Java version on the server, making sure the libraries are included, ... But alas, I'm stuck.

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause    

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:309)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:338)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:171)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:363)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

All important libraries for the project are added in the WEB-INF, which are the following:

- aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b10.jar
- asm-debug-all-5.0.2.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-collections4-4.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- gson-2.3.1.jar
- hk2-api-2.4.0-b10.jar
- hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar
- hk2-utils-2.4.0-b10.jar
- httpclient-4.4.1.jar
- httpcore-4.4.1.jar
- java-json.jar
- javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
- javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
- javax.inject-2.4.0-b10.jar
- javax.json-1.0.2.jar
- javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
- jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
- jersey-client-1.7.jar
- jersey-client.jar
- jersey-common.jar
- jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
- jersey-container-servlet.jar
- jersey-core-1.7.jar
- jersey-guava-2.17.jar
- jersey-json-1.7.jar
- jersey-media-jaxb.jar
- jersey-server.jar
- joda-time-2.3.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
- org.restlet.ext.gson-2.3.1.jar
- org.restlet.ext.json.jar
- org.restlet.jar
- osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
- persistence-api-1.0.jar
- unboundid-ldapsdk-se.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar

Comment: I believe this is not because of missing jar.. I believe it is class loading issue. The jersey jars are not being loaded (or) might have been loaded the wrong version.  Could you please check the dependencies properly and check for duplicate jars for jersey in your application.

Comment: You are completely mixing Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x jars. They are not compatible (and will often break your app just having both versions on the classpath). Pick which version you want to use, and use only jars from _that_ version. Or better jet, use Maven, and let it get all the dependencies for you so you don't lose your hair playing guessing games

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not because of missing jar.. I believe it is class loading issue. The jersey jars are not being loaded (or) might have been loaded the wrong version. Could you please check the dependencies properly and check for duplicate jars for jersey in your application.

Also Please try by undeploying appliation and deploying again.. This might remove all the classes that were already loaded for taht application and Tomcat might intialize class loading again..

Hope this works...